# Cloning identical VM replica in VirtualBox 6.0

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, clone

Virtual Box 6.0 here. I have a Windows 10 VM that is taking up enormous disk space on my host machine (Mac OS) and I would like to save the entire VM and all its associated files off to a flash drive until I can find a different host to run this VM on. That way I can have it backed up but can also delete it from my Mac.

So basically, I'm looking for a **Save to disk** or **Clone to disk** feature, where I can save off an *exact* copy of the VM to another location.

I can't find any options that are obvious here. I see `Machine >> Clone` which looks very promising. However I know that there are lots of different files involved with making a Virtual Box VM, and I'm worried that the clone won't be as complete as I'm looking for it to be.

Can someone with Virtual Box experience confirm that `Machine >> Clone` will produce a 2nd identical copy of my Windows 10 VM, and that it will allow me to save that clone to a flash drive? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Another approach (assuming you have updated the Windows 10 machine) is to do a Disk Cleanup, and Cleanup System Files. When the cleanup dialogue comes up, select ALL items for cleanup including old Windows installs (windows.old). Let that finish. You could save up to 30 GB.  Then shrink the VBOX guest.  https://www.howtogeek.com/312883/how-to-shrink-a-virtualbox-virtual-machine-and-free-up-disk-space/

Comment: Thanks @John (+1) thats an interesting idea. Do you have any experience with `Machine >> Clone`, and if so, would that do what I need it to do? Or does it _not_ actually clone the entire machine? The idea is I could clone it to a flash drive, copy it from the flash to another PC, and then start it up on that PC and be staring at the exact same VM, with the exact same file system, etc.

Comment: Cloning or copying the machine will only reduce space if you reduce space in the machine first. Otherwise it will not reduce space. Otherwise you may need to offload data to a USB drive. I prefer to keep the machines small if I can.

Comment: Thanks @John sorry if I didnt make this clear in the question: I don't care about the disk space. It can be as big as it wants. I just want it off my Mac laptop, but I will need to be able to use it again on another host machine in the future. So, space considerations aside, whats your confidence level that `Machine >> Clone` to a flash drive will truly copy the entire VM and its disk to the flash drive?

Comment: My own Virtual Machines stay within the Fixed Disk size I allotted for them. Generally 100 GB allowed (only use what it needed) for a modern 64-bit machine.

Comment: That's awesome!

Comment: You could simply copy/compress the VM files wherevere your installation is saving them. Cloning a VM generally involves some minor virtual hardware changes.

Comment: Thanks @eventHandler (I would give your comment a +1 but now because of the bounty I don't have enough rep!) - hey whatever it takes! If you think you have a solution, by all means, please add an answer here with specific steps for me to take and I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may read about cloning in the article
[How To Clone Virtual Machine in VirtualBox](https://protechgurus.com/clone-virtual-machine-virtualbox/),
but that doesn't help to export a VM to another computer,
as it only creates a copy on the local computer.

Instead, you should export the VM as an appliance,
move the appliance to the new host,
and then import it. The method to use is described below.

**On the source host**

- Power down the VM.
- In the VirtualBox main window, click *File > Export Appliance*.
- In the resulting window, locate and select the VM to be exported and click *Next*.
- In the next window, select the location to hold the exported appliance file
  and its format. The default of `.ova` will save the appliance
  as a single file and is to be preferred.
  The default format usually works fine.
- After you name the appliance and select the format, click *Next*.
- In the final screen, review the settings and click *Export*
- Wait patiently for the export to terminate.

**On the target host**

- Make available the exported `.ova` file.
- In VirtualBox use menu *File > Import Appliance*.
- Browse to the `.ova` file.
- Click *Next*.
- Review the Appliance settings.
- Click *Import*.
- When the import completes the VM is ready to use.

For more information and screenshots see the article
[How to export VirtualBox virtual machines as appliances](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-export-virtualbox-virtual-machines-as-appliances/).

Comment: Thanks @harrymc! Another user (eventHandler) is warning against potential changes to the virtual hardware's UUID which could deactivate the Windows guest. With your suggested method, exporting it as an appliance, would this changed UUID/deactivated guest problem be an issue for me? Thanks again!

Comment: I believe this will export the VM as-is without changes and Windows should remain activated. However, avoid running two VMs with the same license at the same time. I don't know if Microsoft can detect this, but it might be a risk.

Comment: It's illegal and impossible to hand-off an activated Windows VM. You need to sysprep it first, so as to return it to inactivated status Otherwise you risk Microsoft blacklisting your license.

Comment: If you give away an activated VM, then you have also given away your Windows license.

Answer (score 2):

Cloning a VM generally involves changing virtual hardware's UUID. Therefore, despite of getting an exact copy of your data, your Windows guest will get deactivated. It is possible to revert UUID changes simply modifying some files, though.

Copying the VM files will keep its virtual hardware intact, so Windows won't lose its activation.

1- locate the VM folder in your Mac.

2- copy the folder to the new host.

3- open Virtualbox in the new host and go to machine -> add.

4- select the vbox file in the VM folder.

Comment: Thanks again @eventHandler! Would exporting my VM as an appliance cause this "changed UUID/deactivated guest" problem for me as well?

Comment: Afaik, it is the same as copying the files directly, except that copying files can be quicker. You can send them over the network directly, without using more disk space for the export. You don't waste time in the export/import steps.

Comment: Also, additionally to this answer, which is correct and it is the solution, VirtualBox has option to compact virtual media, which it is advised to use on virtual drive to minimize time of copying process.

Comment: It is legally correct to do this, as it is considered a manual migration from one host to another. However, you must not keep the VM folder in the old host or turn it on. You may keep it as a backup, but not for using it.